# Vue, separate out component templates

Tags: vue.js

I have got a rather large template at the moment for my component. I want to separate aspects of this into it's own component.

However i'm struggling to pass data to this component. I still want to be able to manipulate the data within the child and have the data in the parent update. So for example if I pass in an object, and then use `v-model` within the child on a textbox, the changes should reflex within the parent.

So, i'd assume as I loop through the list of objects I would `v-model` them into my child component, like so:

**Main.vue**

```
<card v-for="quote in quotes" v-model="quote"></card>
```

And then of course accept the input within the new model:

**Card.vue**

```
export default {
        props: [ 'input' ]
    }
```

However i'm getting the following error and I can't really make sense of it.

> You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-mode
>   l on an object property instead.

Comment: See if `v-for="(q,index) in quotes" v-model="quotes[index]"` works?

Comment: Spot on thanks! @MatJ